# Static Table View Cell Labels are getting Squished into Header

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

## EDIT

My constraints on custom cells are all weird.  Please disregard.  Just using standard `Left Detail` ones now.

I don't understand why in iOS8 now my static table view cell contents are collapsing into the header of each section.

[image]

[image]

There's really almost nothing in my `SettingsTVC.m`.  This is a just a test with all static data in the storyboard:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Plz show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Can you post your storyboard?

Comment: Compare height value enter in heightForHeaderInSection method and in Size Inspector.

Comment: I don't have a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  Do I need one for a static table?

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented TableView delegate methods properly i.e

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == CUSTOM_SECTION)
    {
        return CUSTOM_VALUE;
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return height; 
}
```

Comment: You've got an extra semicolon.  yes, I've implemented those two delegate methods and still no difference.

Comment: Is there nothing else I can try?